# Asynchronous operations in Twisted blocked by keyboard I/O

Tags: python, asynchronous, udp, twisted

I'm getting started with asynchronous programming using Twisted, and I came across this simple problem which I'm not sure how to approach. A quick break-down the problem is provided below:

- Server 1 is an UDP server listening on a given port of my host.
- Server 1 exposes an API of operations for, say, data processing.
- Server 2 is also an UDP server listening on a different port of my host.
- Server 2 is running a while-loop where it gets I/O from the user to select a request that will be sent to Server 1. Think for example, a request for calculating the factorial of a number.
- Upon getting input from the user, Server 2 makes an asynchronous call to Server 1. This call has an associated callback to process the response that will be obtained from Server 1.
- Upon making the call, the loops reaches the call where it asks the user for I/O again. I can see in the log that Server 1 processes the request and sends a response, **but the callback in Server 2 is never executed!** Once I break from the while-loop the callback executes.

I tried running the I/O code in a separate thread, but I wasn't able to figure out how to make the operation non-blocking. Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might fix this problem?

Thank you for your time!

Edit 1. Here is the code that Server 2 is executing (the one with the I/O loop making the requests)

```
# Not including the Twisted code
addr = ("Server 1's IP", "Server 1's Port Number")

# Server class implements the functions to make calls and callbacks that act on responses from Server 1
chordServer = Server(2, "This server's IP", "This Server's port")

server = internet.UDPServer(8468, chordServer.protocol)
server.setServiceParent(application)

def controlLoop(q):
    command = None
    while 1:
        command = input("Enter command: \n 1) join network \n 2) leave network \n 3) store key \n 4) fetch key\n 5) exit\n")
        if command == 1:
            print ">>> Executing Join Network Comand!"
            q.put(command)
        elif command == 2:
            print ">>> Executing Leave Network Comand!"
            q.put(command)
        elif command == 3:
            continue
        elif command == 4:
            continue
        elif command == 5:
            q.put(command)
        #time.sleep(1)

def main():
    cmd_queue = Queue.Queue()

    dj = threading.Thread(target=controlLoop, args=(cmd_queue,))
    dj.start()

    while 1:
        cmd = cmd_queue.get()
        if cmd == 5:
            break # Only after breaking does the callback associated with the calls below execute
        elif cmd == 1:
            chordServer.joinNetwork(addr) # Async call to Server 1
        elif cmd == 2:
            chordServer.leaveNetwork() # Another possible Async call to Server 1

task.deferLater(reactor, 5, main)
```

Comment: We might be able to help, if you post your code.

Comment: There's a lot of it, I'll try to abstract it into a simple example @KlausD.

Comment: @KlausD. I added the code that Server 2 is executing. I feel like this must be an idiotic mistake, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a misunderstanding of Twisted. In Twisted the reactor runs a main command loop that handles all the events. You implemented two loops yourself which never terminate. This way the reactors loop is never reached again and Twisted can not work. What you need is to use deferred objects and callbacks. But I'm aware that Twisted is complex and involves a lot of thinking in way that are different from "normal" programming, this makes the topic too complex to handle it here. Maybe you should do the finger tutoria. It teaches you the basic concepts step by step: http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tutorial/index.html

Comment: I'm definitely not very experienced with Twisted, or asynchronous processing in general, but I think this is a simple issue which I'm totally failing to see. Is there a way to execute an asynchronous call such that it blocks execution? Thanks again!

Comment: Blocking the execution is pretty much the opposite of an asynchronous call. If you make a blocking call in Twisted, it will block the whole reactor.